# retrieving a salt from database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a database associated with my winforms program. It stores name, usertype, hash and salt. Ive sorted the registration and writing details, but i dont know how to save the salt (when read from database) as a variable. Here is my code:

```
public string getSalt()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS; database=loginsTest;Trusted_Connection=yes");
        connection.Open();
        string selection = "select DISTINCT Salt from Logins where Name = '"+userNameBox.Text+"'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selection, connection);
        if (command.ExecuteScalar() != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
            return selection;
        }
        else
        {
            connection.Close();
            return "Error";
        }
    }
```

As you can see, its returning selection, which is "select DISTINCT Salt from Logins where Name = '"+userNameBox.Text+"'". How do i save the salt as the variable to return?

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: but im using salts and hashing? so how do i return the salt?

Comment: It's not the salt/hash that's the security problem (though people get that wrong often enough, too). It's the way you build the query.

Comment: so how would i improve it? and would i return the salt as a string?

Comment: i have, it solved my problem but i dont understand how that makes it more secure?

Comment: Think about what would happen if I put something like this into the username field: `';drop table Logins;--`

Comment: To elaborate, with the suggested input, the first character (single quote) would close the string literal in the sql statement. The second character (semi-colon) would end the statement and allow the database to process an additional statement. The next set of characters **drops your table**. Yes, Sql Server will really execute that statement. The final two characters (dashes) comment out anything remaining, so that a syntax error doesn't prevent Sql Server from running/committing the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, and also fixes the gaping sql injection vulnerability in the original:

```
public string getSalt()
{
    string sql = "select DISTINCT Salt from Logins where Name = @username"; 

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS; database=loginsTest;Trusted_Connection=yes")) 
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        //guessing at the column length here. Use actual column size instead of 20
        command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = userNameBox.Text;

        connection.Open();
        return (command.ExecuteScalar() as string) ?? "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) though the string result; was never used, so i removed it but it still works! Is this a more secure way of writing the code as well??

Comment: Yes, this is more secure. **Always** use query parameters for putting user data into a query, and use `using` blocks to ensure that your database connections get closed in the case where an exception is thrown.

Comment: oh, and selection had to be changed to sql. But thank you, ive learnt 2 things now! :)